# prevent immediate Radio :checked property on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click event handler attached to a group of radio inputs, and want to see if I am clicking on the radio button that is already selected (has property 'checked' set). I figured the event handler would act in a daisy chained fashion (first calling my event handler on the click and then continuing down the chain to the default behavior of the click). Apparently this is not the case, because when I evaluate if the property 'checked' is true on the radio button I just clicked, it always returns true in my click event handler.

The click has already been processed by the default behavior and has already applied the 'checked' property to the radio button I just clicked. Again, I figured my click event handler would be processed prior to that default behavior. What's even more odd is that even when I prevent the default behavior, it still returns true for the 'checked' property. I assume this is because the 'checked' property is being processed by the 'change' event, so preventing the default behavior on my click event handler is not affecting anything.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  alert($(this).prop("checked")); // always returns true; i want prop value immediately prior to click
});
```

How can I achieve what I'm after? That is, to see whether or not the radio button that was just clicked on was the one already checked. Thanks.

Comment: I reckon you're better off writing code which captures the id attribute of the default-checked radio button as soon as the page loads, then just modify your onclick code to check whether the radio button which fired the event has the id which matches the pre-checked id you've already stored. Trying to fight the way that the event chain works will probably just result in frustration.

Comment: Since you cannot have more than one radio checked, you can just keep track of the last checked radio and compare.

Comment: Capture mousedown instead of click.

Comment: Jeffman - looks like this prevents the label also registering as a click for the radio button.

plalx - that's a consideration, but if I have 50 radio groups on the page, I don't want to have to keep track of each and every group. Would be nice to have a solution that works for all of them.

Comment: Well, yes. If you kill the mousedown, you kill the click, and the same will be true of an associated label. If you want separate handlers for the label and the button (I'm not sure if that's what you're saying) you need more complicated logic.

Comment: If I have both a click event handler and a change event handler, the click always fires before the change. Setting preventDefault() in the click handler prevents the change event from firing. But I still find it peculiar that it doesn't prevent the click from actually selecting the radio button. Why?

Comment: @Jeffman As your answer implied (though wasn't explicitly said) the radio button selection occurs at mousedown, so I did need to capture on that event. That should be enough to give the solution I wanted. If you want to write that as answer, I'll accept that as the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the response of @Jeffman , I was able to get something to work for what I needed to do. I have custom buttons, only one of which can be selected (hence the use of radio buttons). However, if you click on the one that's already selected, it should deselect and select the default value instead.

Things I had to do. Handle mousedown events on the radio labels. If I am clicking on the already selected radio, set the default button to be 'checked'. Else I just select the button that has been clicked on. I had to disable the 'click' event on these buttons, as that would override my irregular handling of the radio buttons (for some reason the selection would snap back to the one that was clicked when I overrode it and chose the default one manually). This also meant I would need to manually trigger the change event, as I do the custom radio button styling there.

```
$(".radios > label").mousedown(function(e) {

var l = $(this); // label
var t = l.parent(); // container for radio group
var i = l.find("input"); // input element of this label

if(i.prop("checked")) { // clicking on the already selected button
    t.find(".default_radio input").prop("checked", true).trigger("change");     
} else {
    i.prop("checked", true).trigger("change");
}
}).bind('click',false);

$("input[type='radio']").change(function(e) {

    // style the buttons here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Save radio status before click via mousedown

```
var was_checked;  
  $( "#radio" ).mousedown(function() {       
     was_checked = $(this)[0].checked;             
  });

  $( "#radio" ).click(function() {               
        $(this).attr('checked', !was_checked);      
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should also return false. not only preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that would do the trick

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var radios = {};

    $("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
        radios[$(this).uniqueId().attr('id')] = false;
    });
    function resetRadioState() {
        $("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
            radios[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).is(':checked');
        });
    }
    resetRadioState();
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(e) {
        alert(radios[$(this).attr('id')]);
        resetRadioState();
    });
})
</script>

<input type="radio" name="group[]"/>
<input type="radio" name="group[]" checked/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying to avoid the need of storing previous values, as this gets unwieldy when you have tons of radio groups on the page. I was looking for an event based solution, and @Jeffman's note on the use of mousedown got me to the sort of solution I was after. See above.